# Swift - First UIView Controller not responding after calling popviewcontroller() from second

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, pushviewcontroller, popviewcontroller

**Steps:**
1. Navigating from first ViewController **ViewController1** to second ViewController **TamilVowelsViewController** by clicking button1
2. User clicks on home button which navigates back to **ViewController1**
3. **ISSUE:** All the buttons in ViewController1 are not responding.

[ViewController1 - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kekI4.jpg)

[TamilVowelsViewController - Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5cML.jpg)

**ViewController1 and TamilVowelsViewController -- Code**

```
//
//  MenuViewController.swift
//  Tamizh Meesai
//
//  Created by Swaroop on 11/2/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Swaroop. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController1: UIViewController {

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds

    let buttonSize: CGFloat = 150
    let buttonRadius: CGFloat = 75
    let buttonSpacing: CGFloat = 30

    let mathImages = ["plus-1-32.png", "minus-1-32.png", "multiple-1-32.png", "minus-1-32.png"]
    let buttonLabel = ["அ","க்","க","ஷ்"]

    var frontCardView: CardView! = nil
    var backCardView: CardView! = nil

    var showingBack = true

    let beautifulBluesTheme = [ UIColor(red: 1/255, green: 31/255, blue: 75/255, alpha: 1),
                            UIColor(red: 3/255, green: 57/255, blue: 108/255, alpha: 1),
                            UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 91/255, blue: 150/255, alpha: 1),
                            UIColor(red: 100/255, green: 151/255, blue: 177/255, alpha: 1),
                            UIColor(red: 179/255, green: 205/255, blue: 224/255, alpha: 1)
                            ]

    let cappuccinoTheme = [ UIColor(red: 75/255, green: 56/255, blue: 50/255, alpha: 1),
                                 UIColor(red: 133/255, green: 68/255, blue: 66/255, alpha: 1),
                                 UIColor(red: 255/255, green: 244/255, blue: 230/255, alpha: 1),
                                 UIColor(red: 60/255, green: 47/255, blue: 47/255, alpha: 1),
                                 UIColor(red: 190/255, green: 155/255, blue: 123/255, alpha: 1)
                        ]
    var selectedTheme: Int = 1

    var button1 = UIButton()
    var button2 = UIButton()
    var button3 = UIButton()
    var button4 = UIButton()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("viewDidLoad")
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

        selectedTheme = Int(arc4random_uniform(2))

        backCardView = CardView(frame: CGRect())
        backCardView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if(selectedTheme == 0) {
            backCardView.backgroundColor = beautifulBluesTheme[Int(arc4random_uniform(5))]
        }else {
            backCardView.backgroundColor = cappuccinoTheme[Int(arc4random_uniform(5))]
        }
        backCardView.layer.cornerRadius = 30

        frontCardView = CardView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width , height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))
        //frontCardView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        frontCardView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        if(selectedTheme == 0) {
            frontCardView.backgroundColor = beautifulBluesTheme[Int(arc4random_uniform(5))]
        }else {
            frontCardView.backgroundColor = cappuccinoTheme[Int(arc4random_uniform(5))]
        }
        frontCardView.layer.cornerRadius = 30


        let label1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect())
        label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label1.text = "தமிழ்"
        label1.textAlignment = .center
        label1.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 72)
        label1.textColor = UIColor.white

        button1 = getButton(buttonId: 0)
        button2 = getButton(buttonId: 1)
        button3 = getButton(buttonId: 2)
        button4 = getButton(buttonId: 3)

        let hStack1 = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [button1,button2])
        hStack1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //hStack1.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        hStack1.frame = CGRect()
        hStack1.distribution = .fillEqually
        hStack1.alignment = .fill
        hStack1.axis = .horizontal
        hStack1.spacing = buttonSpacing

        let hStack2 = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [button3,button4])
        hStack2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //hStack2.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        hStack2.frame = CGRect()
        hStack2.distribution = .fillEqually
        hStack2.alignment = .fill
        hStack2.axis = .horizontal
        hStack2.spacing = buttonSpacing

        let vStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [hStack1,hStack2])
        vStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //vStack.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        vStack.frame = CGRect()
        vStack.distribution = .fillEqually
        vStack.alignment = .fill
        vStack.axis = .vertical
        vStack.spacing = buttonSpacing

        let starStack = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [getStarImage(), getStarImage(), getStarImage(), getStarImage(), getStarImage()])
        starStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        starStack.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: getStarImage().frame.width * 5 , height: getStarImage().frame.height)
        starStack.distribution = .equalSpacing
        starStack.axis = .horizontal
        starStack.alignment = .fill
        starStack.spacing = 0

        let settingsButtonImage = UIImage(named: "gear-1-32.png")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let settingsButton = UIButton()
        //settingsButton.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        //settingsButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        settingsButton.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width - (settingsButtonImage.size.width) - 20, y: view.frame.height - (settingsButtonImage.size.width) - 20, width: (settingsButtonImage.size.width) * 1.25, height: (settingsButtonImage.size.height) * 1.25)
        settingsButton.setImage(settingsButtonImage, for: .normal)
        settingsButton.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        settingsButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cardButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        settingsButton.setImage(settingsButtonImage, for: .normal)
        settingsButton.tintColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.6)
        settingsButton.tag = 4

        let iapButtonImage = UIImage(named: "lock-1-32.png")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let iapButton = UIButton()
        //iapButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        iapButton.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: view.frame.height - (iapButtonImage.size.width) - 20  , width: (iapButtonImage.size.width) * 1.25, height: (iapButtonImage.size.height) * 1.25)
        iapButton.setImage(iapButtonImage, for: .normal)
        iapButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        iapButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cardButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        iapButton.tintColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.6)

        let nextButtonImage1 = UIImage(named: "rightarrow-1-32.png")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let nextButton1 = UIButton()
        //nextButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        nextButton1.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width - (nextButtonImage1.size.width) - 20, y: 10, width: (nextButtonImage1.size.width) * 1.25, height: (nextButtonImage1.size.height) * 1.25)
        nextButton1.setImage(nextButtonImage1, for: .normal)
        nextButton1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        nextButton1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cardButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        nextButton1.tintColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.6)

        let scoreButtonImage = UIImage(named: "star-1-32.png")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let scoreButton = UIButton()
        //scoreButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scoreButton.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: (scoreButtonImage.size.width) * 1.25, height: (scoreButtonImage.size.height) * 1.25)
        scoreButton.setImage(scoreButtonImage, for: .normal)
        scoreButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        scoreButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cardButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        scoreButton.tintColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.6)

        frontCardView.addSubview(label1)
        frontCardView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label1, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: frontCardView, attribute: .centerX , multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        frontCardView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label1, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: frontCardView, attribute: .top , multiplier: 1, constant: 50))

        frontCardView.addSubview(vStack)
        frontCardView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: vStack, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: frontCardView, attribute: .centerX , multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        frontCardView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: vStack, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: frontCardView, attribute: .top , multiplier: 1, constant: view.frame.height * 0.25))
        frontCardView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: vStack, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: frontCardView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0, constant: buttonSize * 2 + buttonSpacing))
        frontCardView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: vStack, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: frontCardView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0, constant: buttonSize * 2 + buttonSpacing))

        frontCardView.addSubview(starStack)
        frontCardView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: starStack, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: frontCardView, attribute: .centerX , multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        frontCardView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: starStack, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: frontCardView, attribute: .bottom , multiplier: 1, constant: -80))

        frontCardView.addSubview(settingsButton)
        frontCardView.addSubview(iapButton)
        frontCardView.addSubview(nextButton1)
        frontCardView.addSubview(scoreButton)

        view.addSubview(backCardView)
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: backCardView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX , multiplier: 1, constant: view.frame.midX))
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: backCardView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY , multiplier: 1, constant: view.frame.midY))
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: backCardView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: view.frame.width))
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: backCardView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: view.frame.height))

        view.addSubview(frontCardView)
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: frontCardView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX , multiplier: 1, constant: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX))
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: frontCardView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY , multiplier: 1, constant: UIScreen.main.bounds.midY))
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: frontCardView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: UIScreen.main.bounds.width))
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: frontCardView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: UIScreen.main.bounds.height))

        //frontCardView.updateConstraints()
        //view.updateConstraints()

        let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,  action: #selector(tapDetected) )
        singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        singleTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)

        //view.didMoveToWindow()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print("viewWillAppear")


        view.layoutSubviews()


    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        print("viewDidLayoutSubviews")
        view.clipsToBounds = false
    }


    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        print("viewWillLayoutSubviews")

        view.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
        view.needsUpdateConstraints()
        view.updateConstraints()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        print("touches: \(touches.count)")
        for touch in touches {
            let location = touch.location(in: self.view)
            print("location: \(location)")
            let point = self.view.convert(location, from:nil)
            print("point: \(point)")
            //let hitLayer = self.view.layer.name
            //print("hitLayer: \(hitLayer)")

            //if let hitLayer = self.view.layer.hitTest(point) {
            /*if hitLayer != nil && hitLayer?.name != nil {
                    print(hitLayer?.name)
                }
            //}*/
        }

    }




    func logViewHierarchy(view: UIView, num: Int) {

        var index = num
        for i in 0..<index {
            print("\t")
        }

        index = index + 1
        print("\(NSStringFromClass(type(of: view))) userInteractionEnabled: \(view.isUserInteractionEnabled)")
        for subview in view.subviews {
            self.logViewHierarchy(view: subview as! UIView, num: index)
        }
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    @IBAction func tapDetected(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let fromView = showingBack ? frontCardView : backCardView
        let toView = showingBack ? backCardView : frontCardView
        let flipDirection: UIViewAnimationOptions = showingBack ? .transitionFlipFromRight : .transitionFlipFromLeft
        let options: UIViewAnimationOptions = [flipDirection, .showHideTransitionViews]
        UIView.transition(from: fromView!, to: toView!, duration: 0.5, options: options, completion: nil)
        showingBack = !showingBack

        if(selectedTheme == 0) {
            backCardView.backgroundColor = beautifulBluesTheme[Int(arc4random_uniform(5))]
            frontCardView.backgroundColor = beautifulBluesTheme[Int(arc4random_uniform(5))]
        }else {
            backCardView.backgroundColor = cappuccinoTheme[Int(arc4random_uniform(5))]
            frontCardView.backgroundColor = cappuccinoTheme[Int(arc4random_uniform(5))]
        }
    }

    func getButton(buttonId: Int) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        //button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonSize, height: buttonSize)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = buttonSize * 0.5
        button.setTitle(buttonLabel[buttonId], for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 84)
        //button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        button.titleLabel?.alpha = 0.8
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.tintColor = UIColor.clear
        button.tag = buttonId
        //button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
        //button.isEnabled = true

        let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.regular))
        blur.frame = button.bounds
        blur.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        blur.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
        blur.clipsToBounds = true

        button.insertSubview(blur, belowSubview: button.titleLabel!)
        return button
    }

    func getStarImage() -> UIImageView{
        let starImage = UIImage(named: "star-1-32.png")
        let starImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (starImage?.size.width)!, height: (starImage?.size.height)!))
        starImageView.image = starImage

        return starImageView
    }

    @IBAction func buttonAction(button: UIButton!) {
        print("action")
        button.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.6, y: 0.6)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                       delay: 0,
                       usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5,
                       initialSpringVelocity: 4.0,
                       options: .allowUserInteraction,
                       animations: { [weak self] in
                        button.transform = .identity
            },
                       completion:  {(finished:Bool) in

                        if(button.tag == 0) {
                        let tamilVowelsViewController = TamilVowelsViewController()
                            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tamilVowelsViewController, animated: false)
                        }

        })
    }

    @IBAction func cardButtonAction(button: UIButton!) {
        button.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                       delay: 0,
                       usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5,
                       initialSpringVelocity: 4.0,
                       options: .allowUserInteraction,
                       animations: { [weak self] in
                        button.transform = .identity
            },
                       completion: nil)
    }



}


**TamilVowelsViewController**


//
//  TamilVowelsViewController.swift
//  Tamizh Meesai
//
//  Created by Swaroop on 11/5/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Swaroop. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class TamilVowelsViewController: UIViewController {

    var vowelsCardView: CardView! = nil
    var frontCardView: CardView! = nil
    var backCardView: CardView! = nil

    let buttonSize: CGFloat = 100
    let hButtonSpacing: CGFloat = 30
    let vButtonSpacing: CGFloat = 10

    let tamilLetters: TamilLetters = TamilLetters()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        vowelsCardView = CardView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
        //vowelsCardView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        vowelsCardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        vowelsCardView.layer.cornerRadius = 30

        let label1 = UILabel(frame: CGRect())
        label1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label1.text = "உயிர்"
        label1.textAlignment = .center
        label1.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 56)
        label1.alpha = 0.8
        label1.textColor = UIColor.white

        var lettersStack: UIStackView = UIStackView()

        let vStack = UIStackView()
        vStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        vStack.frame = CGRect()
        vStack.distribution = .fillEqually
        vStack.alignment = .fill
        vStack.axis = .vertical
        vStack.spacing = hButtonSpacing

        var vowelId: Int = 0
        var vowelCount = tamilLetters.vowels.count
        for vowel in tamilLetters.vowels {
            let vowelButton = getVowelButton(vowelId: vowelId)
            if(vowelId % 3 == 0) {
                //print("1")
                lettersStack = UIStackView()
                lettersStack.frame = CGRect()
                lettersStack.distribution = .fillEqually
                lettersStack.alignment = .fill
                lettersStack.axis = .horizontal
                lettersStack.spacing = hButtonSpacing

                vStack.addArrangedSubview(lettersStack)
                lettersStack.addArrangedSubview(vowelButton)
            }else {
                //print("2")
                lettersStack.addArrangedSubview(vowelButton)
            }
            vowelId = vowelId + 1
        }

        let homeButtonImage = UIImage(named: "home-3-48.png")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
        let homeButton = UIButton()
        //scoreButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        homeButton.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: (homeButtonImage.size.width) * 1.25, height: (homeButtonImage.size.height) * 1.25)
        homeButton.setImage(homeButtonImage, for: .normal)
        homeButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        homeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cardButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        homeButton.tintColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.6)
        homeButton.tag = 0

        vowelsCardView.addSubview(homeButton)

        vowelsCardView.addSubview(label1)
        vowelsCardView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label1, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: vowelsCardView, attribute: .centerX , multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        vowelsCardView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: label1, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: vowelsCardView, attribute: .top , multiplier: 1, constant: 5))

        vowelsCardView.addSubview(vStack)
        vowelsCardView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: vStack, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: vowelsCardView, attribute: .centerX , multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        vowelsCardView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: vStack, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: vowelsCardView, attribute: .top , multiplier: 1, constant: view.frame.height * 0.11))
        vowelsCardView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: vStack, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: vowelsCardView, attribute: .width, multiplier: 0, constant: buttonSize * 3 + hButtonSpacing * 2))
        vowelsCardView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: vStack, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: vowelsCardView, attribute: .height, multiplier: 0, constant: buttonSize * 4 + vButtonSpacing * 3))


        frontCardView = CardView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
        //frontCardView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        frontCardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.brown
        frontCardView.layer.cornerRadius = 25


        view.addSubview(vowelsCardView)
        /*view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: vowelsCardView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerX , multiplier: 1, constant: view.frame.midX))
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: vowelsCardView, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .centerY , multiplier: 1, constant: view.frame.midY))
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: vowelsCardView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: view.frame.width))
        view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: vowelsCardView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: view.frame.height))

        view.updateConstraints()
        view.layoutIfNeeded()*/

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    func getVowelButton(vowelId: Int) -> UIButton {
        let button = UIButton()
        //button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonSize, height: buttonSize)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = buttonSize * 0.5
        //button1.setImage(UIImage(named: "mathImages[0]", for: .normal)
        button.setTitle(tamilLetters.vowels[vowelId], for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 56)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.tintColor = UIColor.clear
        button.tag = vowelId

        let blur = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.light))
        blur.frame = button.bounds
        blur.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        blur.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * button.bounds.size.width
        blur.clipsToBounds = true

        button.insertSubview(blur, belowSubview: button.titleLabel!)
        return button
    }

    @IBAction func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {

    }

    @IBAction func cardButtonAction(button: UIButton!) {
        /*button.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5,
                       delay: 0,
                       usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5,
                       initialSpringVelocity: 4.0,
                       options: [.allowUserInteraction],
                       animations: { [weak self] in
                        button.transform = .identity
            },
                       completion: nil)*/

     if(button.tag == 0) {

        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true;
        //self.view.clipsToBounds = true;
     }


    }



}
```

**Steps:**
1. Navigating from first ViewController **ViewController1** to second ViewController **TamilVowelsViewController** by clicking button1
2. User clicks on home button which navigates back to **ViewController1**
3. **ISSUE:** All the buttons in ViewController1 are not responding.

Comment: Did you tried what is happening with the gesture you are adding here in View , When you come back to viewcontroller1 try using breakpoints is anything being called or not like gesture action and all you r button actions

Comment: isUserInteractionEnabled = true maybe it's false when you come back.